# How many nodes/shards for elasticsearch, and how much RAM

Tags: elasticsearch

So I've really got two questions here.

1. If I have about 100GB of documents that I want to make searchable with elasticsearch, is it bad to just stick it in a single node / shard? ( I can figure out replicas later when we start looking at production)
2. Also, how much RAM do I need? Is it possible to run this ES instance on a machine with only 8gb ram or something (just during development) and just have it run slower, or do I need to need shell out now for a system with more memory?

My use case is that I am prototyping a system and need to get our full document set indexed so we can compare it apples to apples in usability testing against the existing system. Performance isn't huge right now. My dev machine is just a i7 ultrabook with 8gb of ram, and for the first, smaller version of the prototype that only had about 30mb of documents, my machine was just fine. Is it even possible for me to use this machine for dev with the next version of the prototype or do I need to shell out now for a more powerful machine?